# Why do this return an empty string?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm doing a project in jQuery and used a code to take value from a cell at index 'loc', but its always returning an empty string while doing so. It works when I use :

```
$("#lastTable tr td:nth-child(1)").eq(loc).text();
```

But it's not working when I use:

```
$("#lastTable td").children(1).eq(loc).text();
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code. From the jquery code alone we can't tell you the problem. But `$("#lastTable td").children(1)` and `$("#lastTable tr td:nth-child(1)")` is not the same

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: They're very different selectors. Perhaps you ment to use `tr` instead of `td` in the second version ? And that's assuming `.children(1)` does what you mean, i'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#lastTable tr td:nth-child(1)").eq(loc)` take the `loc` cell of the collection of first nth-children

`$("#lastTable td").children(1).eq(loc).text();` take the loc element of the children of all cells in the table

The `1` is ignored in the .children since .children takes a selector

```js
loc = 1

$("#lastTable td").children() // takes a selector
  .css({color:"red" })
  .eq(loc).text("Hello");
  
$("#lastTable tr td:nth-child(1)")
  .css({color:"green" })
.eq(loc).text("World")
```

```css
span { border:1px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="lastTable">
<tbody>
<tr><td><span>row 1</span> <span>cell 1</span></td><td><span>row 1</span> <span>cell 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>row 2</span> <span>cell 1</span></td><td><span>row 2</span> <span>cell 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>row 3</span> <span>cell 1</span></td><td><span>row 3</span> <span>cell 2</span></td></tr>

</tbody></table>
```